# Android external keyboard layout switch

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have and Android tablet and using external keyboard with it.

Is there any shortcut or another quick way to change keyboard layout on the fly (like on desktop, e.g. Alt+Shift)?

Answer (score -1):

Try Shift + Space Bar
It works with Samsung TabS on Logitech Keyboard